# How do I dynamically print explanations for the current options used in linux commands?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a linux tool that upon for example when I run:

```
ls -lrt
```

will not only print the result but will also print

```
ls - list files
-l - show extended list
-r - reverse
-t - sort by time
AND ONLY NOW PRINT THE RESULTS
```

the reason is that it would be cool if it could always remind me what the options that i'm using are actually are! :)

Is there anything like this to print dynamically the help for the options I'm currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a "pre-execution" function of some sorts, then have it pick out the actual options used at an instance of a call and translate that into e.g.

```
$ man ls | grep -E  '^[ \t]+(-l|-r|-t)'
       -l     use a long listing format
       -r, --reverse
       -t     sort by modification time, newest first
```

... for an `ls -lrt`.